# Select data from different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have a table: BID

```
Id_auction        bidder_1      winner_1    bidder_2    winner_2    item
  1                Alice           1          Ben         1          cup
  2               Charles          0          Alice       1          mug
  3                 Ben            1          Charles     1          pen
```

If a bidder is a winner the value is 1 if is not a winner the value is 0. So, in first auction, Alice and Ben are winners, in the second only Alice wins. I will need a MySQL query so the results will be like this:

```
Id_auction       bidder        item      bidder_number
1                Alice         cup            1
1                Ben           cup            2
2                Alice         mug            2
3                Ben           pen            1
3                Charles       pen            2
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    t1.id_auction,
    t2.bidder_1 AS bidder,
    t2.item
  FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table1 t2  ON t1.id_auction = t2.id_auction
                       AND t2.winner_1 = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    t1.id_auction,
    t2.bidder_2 AS bidder,
    t2.item
  FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table1 t2  ON t1.id_auction = t2.id_auction
                       AND t2.winner_2 = 1
) AS sub
ORDER BY id_auction;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1990e/3)

This will give you:

```
| ID_AUCTION |  BIDDER | ITEM |
-------------------------------
|          1 |   Alice |  cup |
|          1 |     Ben |  cup |
|          2 |   Alice |  mug |
|          3 | Charles |  pen |
|          3 |     Ben |  pen |
```

---

### Update 1

Just select a new column `bidder_number` with value 1 in the first query, and 2 in the second one like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    t1.id_auction,
    t2.bidder_1 AS bidder,
    t2.item,
    1 AS bidder_number        -- <---------- This is the new column
  FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table1 t2  ON t1.id_auction = t2.id_auction
                       AND t2.winner_1 = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    t1.id_auction,
    t2.bidder_2 AS bidder,
    t2.item,
    2                         -- < --------- with value 2 for bidders 2
  FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table1 t2  ON t1.id_auction = t2.id_auction
                       AND t2.winner_2 = 1
) AS sub
ORDER BY id_auction, bidder;
```

This will give you:

```
| ID_AUCTION |  BIDDER | ITEM | BIDDER_NUMBER |
-----------------------------------------------
|          1 |   Alice |  cup |             1 |
|          1 |     Ben |  cup |             2 |
|          2 |   Alice |  mug |             2 |
|          3 |     Ben |  pen |             1 |
|          3 | Charles |  pen |             2 |
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1990e/8)

Comment: @ Mahmoud Gamal - Can you help me again? I need to modify your query so I will know the number of the bidder. In your demo it will be another field with the value bidder_1 for Alice on ID_AUCTION 1, bidder_2 for Ben on ID_AUCTION 1 and so on. Sorry!

Comment: @MugurUngureanu - Sure, any time. But, Sorry, I didn't understand. Can you please edit your question and show me the result that you want? It will be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question. I want to know if the winner of the auction is the first bidder (bidder_1), the second (bidder_2) and so on. I must be true to you that this is only a part of the querry, the table is more complex but I know how to solve the rest of the problems. :)

Comment: Of course! Thank you again! :)) Have a nice and peaceful afternoon!

Comment: @MugurUngureanu - You are welcome any time :) And have a nice and peaceful afternoon you too, but it is the night now here  :)

Comment: Hei, can you help me again with this problem? I asked a new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680774/select-data-from-different-columns-and-two-tables)