# Select data from different columns and two tables

Tags: mysql, select, join

I already asked (and solved) something close 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875360/select-data-from-different-columns)
but now is more complicated. I have the same BID table:

```
Id_auction        bidder_1      winner_1    bidder_2    winner_2    item
  1                Alice           1          Ben         1          cup
  2               Charles          0          Alice       1          mug
  3                 Ben            1          Charles     1          pen
```

But now I want to join the information with another table USD

```
Id_auction         USD
1                  100
2                  150
3                   50
```

If a bidder is a winner the value is 1 if is not a winner the value is 0. So, in first auction, Alice and Ben are winners, in the second only Alice wins. I will need a MySQL query so the results will be like this:

```
  Id_auction       bidder        item      bidder_number   USD
  1                Alice         cup            1          100
  1                Ben           cup            2          100
  2                Alice         mug            2          150
  3                Ben           pen            1           50
  3                Charles       pen            2           50
```

Thank you!

Comment: First normalize your data

Comment: Could you recreate the tables with content in mysqlfiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `JOIN` with this table `USD`:

```
SELECT sub.*, USD.USD
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    t1.id_auction,
    t2.bidder_1 AS bidder,
    t2.item,
    1 AS bidder_number    
  FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table1 t2  ON t1.id_auction = t2.id_auction
                       AND t2.winner_1 = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    t1.id_auction,
    t2.bidder_2 AS bidder,
    t2.item,
    2                    
  FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table1 t2  ON t1.id_auction = t2.id_auction
                       AND t2.winner_2 = 1
) AS sub
INNER JOIN USD ON sub.id_auction = USD.id_auction
ORDER BY id_auction, bidder;
```

[**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27b6d/1)

```
| ID_AUCTION |  BIDDER | ITEM | BIDDER_NUMBER | USD |
-----------------------------------------------------
|          1 |   Alice |  cup |             1 | 100 |
|          1 |     Ben |  cup |             2 | 100 |
|          2 |   Alice |  mug |             2 | 150 |
|          3 |     Ben |  pen |             1 |  50 |
|          3 | Charles |  pen |             2 |  50 |
```

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Now you have a Fan Club :) Thank you!

Comment: @MugurUngureanu - You're welcome any time :). No,  I know him and he someone like an old brother for me :)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - I am asking you again because you already understood my problem. I added on table USD some fields (Paid) because some customers, winners af the bidding, failed to pay. So I will need to know that. Paid values can be 0 - not paid or 1 - paid. So I will need in the result table, in the USD column only "paid" money. In my sample Ben, winner at the first auction, failed to pay so I will need to have "nothing" for him in the USD column. I tried here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66518/1

Comment: @MugurUngureanu - Can you please show me the expected result in this case? Please edit your question and post that.

Comment: @MugurUngureanu - Do you means [**something like in this demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66518/6)??

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Sorry, I was out of the office. Yes, thank you! I was trying to do this as a WHEN at the last part of the script. But you are right! Take care!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  BID.Id_auction AS Id_auction,
  BID.bidder_1 AS bidder,
  BID.item AS item,
  USD.USD AS USD,
  1 AS bidder_number
FROM BID
INNER JOIN USD ON BID.Id_auction=USD.Id_auction
WHERE BID.winner_1=1

UNION ALL

SELECT
  BID.Id_auction AS Id_auction,
  BID.bidder_2 AS bidder,
  BID.item AS item,
  USD.USD AS USD,
  2 AS bidder_number
FROM BID
INNER JOIN USD ON BID.Id_auction=USD.Id_auction
WHERE BID.winner_2=1

ORDER BY BID.Id_auction, budder_number
```